# How do I update geometry column using another column data

Tags: asp.net, geometry, postgis, latitude-longitude, point

I want to update my geometry(point) column with latitude(float) and longitude(float) column.
Table PK column is pk.

I tried to query

```sql
update ucs.target1
set geo_point = st_geomfromtext('point(latitude longitude)')
where pk = 'gd'
```

but syntax error occured.
help me plz....

Comment: Check out the st_point function. I think you need st_point(longitude,latitude)... https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way, try this one by specifying the srid (in here for example for WGS84):

```
update ucs.target1
set geo_point = st_geomfromtext('point(longitude latitude)',4326)
where pk = 'gd'
```

I edit my answer here:

1. Suppose I have table with its structure :

   ```
    CREATE TABLE schema.table_name
    (
        id integer NOT NULL,
        geom_4326 geometry(Point,4326)
    )
   ```
2. Table have already rows, and I want to update the coordinate at a specific id, in here id = 'id_value'.
3. My code is :

   ```
    update schema.table_name
    SET geo_point = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude,latitude), SRID)
    where id = 'id_value'
   ```

SRID in my case = 4326

Comment: um.... no... it's still the same...

Comment: XX000: parse error - invalid geometry has occured.

Comment: I update the answer above!

Comment: thanks your advise, but my intend is some different.

Comment: that is only postgis query.

Comment: I see, in that case you should mention asp.net from the beginning :)

Comment: thanks you !! baovolamda ! i inpired your flavor.